# How to create a mathematical expression in scipy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scipy, sympy

I have been exploring scipy and the core packages of scipy for a math project.

I need to do calculus operations on some equations... so for learning scipy I decided to test a simple equation ([PDF of a normal random variable](https://explorable.com/images/normal-probability-distribution-formula.jpg)). I need to keep the constants as they are during the calculus operations... and not assign a value to it.

I was able to create it successfully using sympy. Here is the code:

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')
mu = Symbol('mu')
sigma = Symbol('sigma')

def normpdfeqn():
    y = exp(-(((x-mu)**2)) / (2*(sigma**2))) / (sqrt(2*pi*(sigma**2)))
    return y

print(integrate(normpdfeqn(), (x)))
```

and got a proper output:

`sigma*erf(sqrt(2)*(-mu + x)/(2*sigma))/(2*sqrt(sigma**2))`

Then I tried to  do the same with scipy.

I have been reading http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html but could not figure out how to create the equation for it. Here is what I have tried till now (it's almost the same as the above code):

```
from sympy import exp
from sympy import sqrt
from sympy import pi
from scipy.integrate import quad
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
mu = Symbol('mu')
sigma = Symbol('sigma')

def integrand():
    y = exp(-((x-mu)**2) / (2*(sigma**2))) / (sqrt(2*pi*(sigma**2)))
    return y


I = quad(integrand(), 0, 1,)
print(I)
```

The code might be far from complete, I do not know how to get it working.

If I would always be working with equations which I showed above, should I bother to learn scipy integrate? Or keep using sympy and numpy?

Comment: If you want to do *symbolic* operations you should use sympy.  Scipy does *numerical* operations.

Comment: @BrenBarn so, I create my equations using sympy and then lambdify (or it was some other function, couldn't remember) them to use the eqn with numpy or scipy... would this workflow be fine?

Comment: Very interesting. Most people separate the two endeavors, because their equations don't change often. But you intend to have an analytical input, then the code doing first the analytical analysis (w/o supervision) and then compute numerical results? This could be ambitious. I like it.

Comment: @roadrunner66 I'm working with my math professor on a project which studies change in signals by changing a few factors. That's the reason why my equations would change frequently.

Comment: @vicky96: I think you could do that, yeah.

Comment: @BrenBarn okay, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This simplified code might be a step towards your goals:

it takes a function, here a quadratic to keep things as simple as possible, and evaluates its closed form integral (using sympy)

Then it numerically evaluates the integral value between 0 and 3 using scipy.

And the closed form integral using the same limits with sympy.

It is a little bit of a prototype, but seems to do what you require.

```
from sympy import *
from scipy.integrate import quad

x = Symbol('x')

def func():
    y = x**2 + 2*x +3
    return y

def integrand(expr):
    y = lambda x: eval(expr)
    return y 


y = repr(func())             # a str representation of the original function

res = integrate(func(), (x)) # a sympy representation of the closed form integral 
                             # of the original function

I = quad(integrand(y), 0, 3) # a scipy numerical integration of the original function

print(y)        # sympy repr of original function
print(I)        # scipy numerical integration of the original function
print()
print(res)      # sympy repr of closed form integral of original function
print(integrand(repr(res))(3) - integrand(repr(res))(0)) # closed form integer evaluation
```

**Resulting output:**

```
x**2 + 2*x + 3
(27.0, 2.9976021664879227e-13)

x**3/3 + x**2 + 3*x
27.0
```